# Should one-time events always be closed as "too localized"?

Tags: discussion, closing

[How can I craft the Golden Wrench in TF2?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/319/how-can-i-craft-the-golden-wrench-in-tf2) seems like a perfectly legitimate question someone might want to Google, with an answer that won't change (with any more likelyhood than an SC2 or WoW question would).

There should be some distinction made between questions about one-off events with lasting effects and others that are meaningless after such a date (When is X coming out?) instead of just closing all questions that are somehow connected to an event.

Comment: I ran into that question when I was doing a deletion run of closed questions. And I was actually thinking the same concern.

Comment: I'd suggest against looking at decisions taken in the first few weeks of existence of Gaming and thinking they're indicative of any kind of current consensus :)

Answer (score 6):

The accepted answer is: **You can no longer craft it**.

That seems like the kind of thing that people would want to know.  Unlike a release date (which you'll only miss if you're hiding under a rock), the desire for an in game item is not localized to the specific time it's obtainable, but continues on for years afterwards.

After all, I'd still kill someone, in front of his own mother, if it got me that damn [Bug Mount](http://www.wowhead.com/spell=26656/black-qiraji-battle-tank)

Comment: The rise in the number of murderous impulses among users on this site is not a very good sign for my future health and continued survival...